# How to set green dot badge to a particular tabBarItem in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbaritem

Currently, I'm trying to set the green dot this way, but end result is always a red badge.

```
        xxxx.tabBarItem.badgeColor = .clear
        xxxx.tabBarItem.badge value = "●"

        
        let attribute : [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.green]

        xxxx.tabBarItem.setBadgeTextAttributes(attribute, for: .disabled)
        xxxx.tabBarItem.setBadgeTextAttributes(attribute, for: .selected)
        xxxx.tabBarItem.setBadgeTextAttributes(attribute, for: .highlighted)
        xxxx.tabBarItem.setBadgeTextAttributes(attribute, for: .normal)
```

What do I want?

[image]

But code result is:
[image]

Comment: What happens if you set `badgeColor = .green` instead of clear?

Comment: Where are you setting all of these tabBarItem  properties in your code? Which method?

Comment: The default value of badgeColor is systemRed. So something tells me you aren't configuring your tabBarItem in the right place. Or maybe you are doing it multiple times with different values.

Comment: @HangarRash same result (it takes default red)

Comment: @RobC I'm setting those in
`func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController)`

Comment: I think I know what's happing, it's all because I was doing `self.tabBar.standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance`

Answer (score 0):

It will work. Use `tabBar.items` instead of `tabBarItem.badgeValue`.

```
 self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[0].badgeColor = .clear

 self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[0].badgeValue = "●"

 let attribute : [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.green]

 self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[0].setBadgeTextAttributes(attribute, for: .disabled)

 self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[0].setBadgeTextAttributes(attribute, for: .selected)

 self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[0].setBadgeTextAttributes(attribute, for: .highlighted)

 self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[0].setBadgeTextAttributes(attribute, for: .normal)
```

[image: ScreenShot]